# Priority queue in java tie break for removing duplicate elements

Tags: java, priority-queue

If there are multiple elements with same value in `PriorityQueue`, while removing from the queue which element is popped?
Is there any specific order in which these same elements are popped?

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific order.  The Javadoc specifies:

> If multiple elements are tied for least value, the head is one of those elements -- ties are broken arbitrarily.